# Decal stuck to wrong side of paper

Tags: car, adhesive

I have a rear window decal that I really want to put on my car. The problem is that it is stuck to the paper on the wrong side. Instead of being where I can apply it and peel the clear sheet off, the sticky side is stuck instead. It's pretty old. Is there a way to make it revert back to the correct side so I can apply it?

I hope this makes sense. It's kind of hard to explain correctly.

Comment: If you want the decal to be visible from the outside, stick it on the inside of the glass. That's the usual thing, then the sticker isn't subjected to wind and rain and power washes. The idea is that you peel the backing paper off first, or just expose one sticky edge and drag the backing off as you apply the decal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If the decal is glued to "paper" side of the paper (instead on the shiny one), then the glue is now useless.
2. `It's pretty old` - there is a good chance that the glue itself is old, regardless of where it is applied.

Long story short, buy another decal, which is not burdened by those problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have taken off many, many decals, stickers and signage at work with a hairdryer. Never ever seen one that could de reglued somewhere else. They seem to always get damaged.

Ps. Do not try to take them off on cold days, if you truly want to try and salvage them. Again I have never seen them undamaged when being peeled off.

My best suggestion is that you buy a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Bend one corner - very slowly peel back the paper with the non-sticky side facing upwards at you. While continuing to deeply press down the letters onto the sticky side of the paper. (helps if using a card or small tool) It should transfer. It worked for me.
Link to a quick help YouTube video.
https://youtu.be/SjLyj3ZsvRY